# Weird behavior with Stack Implementation in C++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, linked-list, stack

EDIT 2: Program now working. Thank you for your help
One last question: 
I allocate memory for top at every push. If I wanted to delete that in pop, would this code work?

```
int pop()
{
cout << "About to pop: " << top->getData() << "\n";
  int retVal = top->getData();
  if(top->getLasty()!=NULL)
 {
  node* temp = top;
  top = top->getLasty();
  delete temp;
  cout << "new data is: " << top->getData() << "\n";
 }
return retVal;
}
};
```

Working Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
  int data;
  node* lasty;

  public:
  node()
  {
   lasty = NULL;
   data = -1;
  }
  node(node* ptr,int dat)
    {
    lasty = ptr;
    data = dat;
    cout << "New node created! Data is " << dat << ", lasty's data is " << ptr->getData() << "\n";
    }
   node* getLasty()
   {
    return lasty;
   }
   int getData()
   {
     return data;
   }
   void setData(int x)
   {
    data = x;
   }

   void setLasty(node* ptr)
   {
    lasty = ptr;
   }
};

class stack
{
node* top;

public:
stack()
{
 cout << "New Stack created!\n";
 top = new node();
}
~stack()
{
delete top;
}

void push(int x)
{
cout << "Before pushing, top's data is " << top->getData() << "\n";
top = new node(top, x);
//node* temp = new node();
//temp->setData(x);
//temp->setLasty(top);
//top = temp;
cout << "TOP'S DATA IS: " << top->getData() << "\n";
cout << "TOP: " << "top lasty's data is: " << top->getLasty()->getData() << "\n\n";
}

int pop()
{
cout << "About to pop: " << top->getData() << "\n";
  int retVal = top->getData();
  if(top->getLasty()!=NULL)
 {
  top = top->getLasty();
  cout << "new data is: " << top->getData() << "\n";
 }
return retVal;
}
};

int main()
{
stack a;
 a.push(1);
 a.push(2);
 a.push(3);
 cout << a.pop();
 cout << a.pop();
    return 0;
}
```

Also turns out I need more text to submit this edit, so consider this filler text.

Comment: Where are you allocating memory for a new node?

Comment: "I'm trying to implement a stack using a linked list..." Why? Why would you do such a horrible thing? It's nearly the worst possible way to implement a stack.

Comment: What about using `std::stack`, or is this homework??

Answer (score 1):

```
stack()
{
 cout << "New Stack created!\n";
 node a = node();
 top = &a;
}
```

Node `a` is local variable so it is destroyed after the body of constructor is passed. Then the pointer `top` refers to destroyed object. You should create it in the heap and delete it later.

```
stack()
{
 cout << "New Stack created!\n";
 top = new Node();
}
```

Comment: OK, I changed the constructor and push method, but it's still producing the same incorrect output! See my edited top post for the new code

Answer (score 0):

Another issue:

```
node(node ptr,int dat)
{

    lasty = &ptr;
    data = dat;
    cout << "New node created! Data is " << dat << ", lasty's data is " << ptr.getData() << "\n";
}
```

You are taking the address of a copied variable.  When `ptr` is passed, the compiler is making a copy of the original item.  This is called pass by value.

Since the name of the variable is `ptr`, I assume you are passing a pointer to a node.  You should assign the value of the pointer, not its address:

```
// Original
// lasty = &ptr;

// Assigning the pointer value:
lasty = ptr;
// Notice removal of `&`.
```

You can assign pointers to pointers.